# Python module Gensim error "cannot import name utils"

Tags: python, pip, gensim, word-embedding

Hi I am using Gensim Word2Vec for word embedding in python.

```
from gensim.models import Word2Vec, KeyedVectors
```

But i am getting error like:

```
from gensim import utils
# cannot import whole gensim.corpora, because that imports wikicorpus...
from gensim.corpora.dictionary import Dictionary
```

ImportError: cannot import name utils. Thank you

Comment: There is a similar question [here](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/issues/623) and also a solution, see if that helps

Comment: No that solution is not helping me out @OferSadan . I have tried that still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue - In my case it was a dependency issue on scipy. I did the following to reinstall scipy.

```
pip uninstall scipy
conda install scipy
```

Hope this helps!